# Using java with android how can I get the path of my resources files?

Tags: android, resources

I added some audio files to the res file.
first I created a raw dir and then I added the folder with the audio files.

How can I get each file path? (I want to use the path to play this audio files)

I found that I need to use

```
classLoader.getResource
```

but I don't understand how. what is the argument for this function?

Answer (score 1):

A reference should be added to your `R` class that you can get as something like `R.raw.sound_file_1`.  Check out the [Audio and Video](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) section of the Android Developer's Guide for more details.

Once you have the reference to your audio clip you can play it by:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
```

So you don't really need the path to the resource at all, just use the reference.

Comment: the link you gave me didn't say anything about using an existing file, it talks only about creating new files.

How can I regenerate the R class so it will contain all the files and folders that I added to the Resources?

Comment: @masterkapu: R should be auto-generated when you build your project.  It gets build using what you put in your /res directory.  Clean and Build your project then look in the /gen directory.

Comment: I did it and it didn't change the R class

Comment: @masterkapu: Sorry, I don't have the Android SDK on this machine, so I'm doing this from memory.  Are you using Eclipse with the Android plug-in?

Comment: It didn't changed cause I put in it only folders with no files
How can I make it to see folers?

Comment: If you put an audio file directly in your /raw directory (instead of a sub-folder) then build, does R get updated?

Comment: If `R` got updated with something like `R.raw.sound_file_1` then you shouldn't need the path.  You can use the reference to the resource to access it.

Comment: How do I do it? Can write it in code please?


How can I divide the res (to folders or anything else)?

Comment: Typically the res folder has subfolders for each type of resource (layouts, drawables, xml files, etc.). You can look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html in the Android developers guide.

Comment: sorry...,I meant the raw folder. Can I do that?

Comment: I don't want to play this file. I need to assign it as a contact ringtone